# Structure Login Success And Failure Features

Tags: grails, cucumber, geb

I'm just getting started with Cucumber and I'm using Geb all inside of a Grails 2.1.1 application.  I've got my first test working which tests a successful login.

```
Feature: login to system
  As a user of the system
  I want to log in to the application
  so that I can use it

  Scenario: login
    Given I access the login page
    When I enter "user_10001" and "10001"
    Then I see the dashboard

Given(~'^I access the login page$') {->
  to LoginPage
  at LoginPage
}

When(~'^I enter "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)"$') { String username, String password ->
  page.add(username, password)
}

Then(~'^I see the dashboard$') {->
  at DashboardPage
}

Then(~'^I see an error message on the login page$') { ->
  at LoginPage
}
```

This works great.  I also want to test what happens when a login fails.  I realize this is another scenario, but is it another feature?  Or is it an additional scenario on the same feature?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A feature is a piece of functionality. The only reason to divide scenarios into more then one feature is to make file less longer and make information about functionality more searchable.

Your scenario is part of Authentication feature. But if you have a lot of functionality related to authentication (several login pages, forgot password, SMS/Phone confirmation), authentication functionality can be divided to several feature files put into authentication folder. It depends on your application

I think in any case scenarios for successful and unsuccessful login will fit better in the same file.

---

Also your scenario looks a bit brittle and imperative to me. Read the following:

- [Imperative vs Declarative Scenarios in User Stories](http://benmabey.com/2008/05/19/imperative-vs-declarative-scenarios-in-user-stories.html)
- [Refactored example from Cucumber book](https://gist.github.com/2057807)

I'd write it like:

```
Scenario: Login
  Given I'm at login page
  When I login with valid credentials
  Then I see the dashboard
```

Comment: Thanks.  I still have a lot to learn.  What is confusing me a bit is for both Scenarios I am starting with the 'Given' is the same.  And I can't tell if my errors are because I can't do that or if it is because I have something else wrong.  But that's a different question...